# How to set mongo.db for server channels discord.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

How do i set mongo .db for remember the channels that are selected for log channels?
Also if its posiblle i wanna to first only ask about the channel when they selected the channel then they can write report command.

```
module.exports = {
        name: 'rapor',
        description: "rapor ",
        execute(message, args,Discord) {
            if (!args[0]){
                message.reply('Who do i reporting?')
                return
            } if (!args[1]){
                message.reply('write a reason for reporting.')
                return
            } if (!args[2]){
                message.reply('What channel do i have to send report message. for first time users we showing this channel select when your log channel is saved you dont have to write your channel again')
                return
            }
            message.channel.send(`${args[0]} User is reported with:**${args[1]}** `)
        }
    }
```